# how can I make a universal function to change the local state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I have `onChangeName` and `onChangeAge` functions, but I want to make 1 function from these two.

functions `onChangeSomeState` does not work, I don't no why

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-waterfall-2y8icf?file=/src/App.js)

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [age, setAge] = useState("");

  const onChangeSomeState = (setFunc) => (event) => {
    setFunc(event.taget.value);
  };

  const onChangeName = (e) => {
    setName(e.target.value);
  };

  const onChangeAge = (e) => {
    setAge(e.target.value);
  };

  const onSubmit = () => {
    const res = JSON.stringify({
      name: name,
      age: age
    });
    console.log(res);
  };

  console.log(name);
  console.log(age);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        onChange={onChangeName}
        placeholder="name"
        value={name}
        className="input"
      />
      <input
        onChange={() => onChangeSomeState(setAge())}
        // onChange={onChangeAge}
        placeholder="age"
        value={age}
        className="input"
      />
      <button onClick={onSubmit} type="button" className="button">
        submit
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'm not getting any `age` value in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
onChange={onChangeSomeState(setAge)}
```

When you do `onChange={() => onChangeSomeState(setAge())}`, you are not passing the `event` to the handler function.

You can also do:

```
onChange={(e) => onChangeSomeState(setAge)(e)}
```

Also there was a typo: `setFunc(event.taget.value);` missing an `r` in `target`